# Haskell parameter is not right?

Tags: haskell

I am new haskell leaner, my code as follows:

```
{-- snippet all --}
{- | Our usual CustomColor type to play with -}
data CustomColor =
  CustomColor {red :: Int,
               green :: Int,
               blue :: Int}
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

{- | A new type that stores a name and a function.

The function takes an Int, applies some computation to it, and returns
an Int along with a CustomColor -}
data FuncRec =
    FuncRec {name :: String,
             colorCalc :: Int -> (CustomColor, Int)}

plus5func color x = (color, x + 5)

purple = CustomColor 255 0 255

plus5 = FuncRec {name = "plus5", colorCalc = plus5func purple }
always0 = FuncRec {name = "always0", colorCalc = \_ -> (purple, 0)}
{-- /snippet all --}
```

In the line "colorCalc=plus5func purple", why there are just one parameter("purple") after plus5func, actually plus5func should need two parameters?

Comment: quick answer: google "partial application" and "currying".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition

```
plus5func color x = (color, x + 5)
```

is equivalent to

```
plus5func color = f
    where f x = (color, x + 5)
```

In other words: `plus5func` actually takes only one argument (`color`) ad returns a function `f`. This returned function takes one argument (`x`) and returns the final color&int pair.

This is the style in which "binary" functions are usually represented in Haskell and other functional languages. This style is named "Currying" after the mathematician/computer scientist "Haskell Curry".

You can use such function as they were binary functions because

```
plus5func color x
= (plus5func color) x
= f x                      {- where f is as above -}
= (color, x + 5)
```

As a bonus you get "partial application", namely the ability of passing *fewer* arguments (one in this case) and getting a function of the remaning arguments to be passed (`f` in this case).

So, the line

```
plus5 = FuncRec {name = "plus5", colorCalc = plus5func purple }
```

actually means

```
plus5 = FuncRec {name = "plus5", colorCalc = f }
     where f x = plus5func purple x
```

Answer (score 3):

All functions in haskell are implicitly [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application). This means that when you write a function like

```
f x y = x + y
```

You're really doing something more like

```
f = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

That is, `f` is a function that maps `x` to another function that maps `y` to `x + y`.

So `f 5` is really the function `\y -> 5 + y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply parameters to a function partially. It means you give the first parameter now and the second parameter later.

For example:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(1+) :: Num a => a -> a
(1+1) :: Num a => a
```